# Cannot receive data when using Signal & Slot in QT

Tags: c++, qt

I have 2 forms which is created by QT Creator. I have used Signal & Slot to transfer data between those 2 forms. But I can't receive any data.

And these are 2 forms in my application

**Form1.h**

```
class Form1: public QDialog
{

...........

private slots:
    void on_btnOK_clicked();

signals:
    void SendId(int id);
};
```

**Form1.cpp**

```
#include "form2.h"

void Form1::on_btnOK_clicked()
{
   emit SendId(2);            //ID = 2

   Form2 form2;
   form2.setModal(true);
   form2.exec();
}
```

**Form2.h**

```
class Form2 : public QDialog
{

...........

public slots:
   void ReceiveId(int id);
private:
   Form1* m_pForm1;
};
```

**Form2.cpp**

```
Form2::Form2(QWidget *parent) :
QDialog(parent),
ui(new Ui::Form2)

{
   ui->setupUi(this);
   m_pForm1 = new Form1(this);

    // Connecting the signal we created in the Form1
    // with the slot created in the Form2
    QObject::connect(m_pForm1, SIGNAL(SendId(int)),
                     this, SLOT(ReceiveId(int)));
}

void Form2::ReceiveId(int id)
{
    qDebug() << "Received id";
}
```

When I run the application, I don't see the message **"Received id"**. Is my application wrong?

Do you have any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you add Q_OBJECT macro?

Comment: Check the return value of connect(), and if there's debug output from the connect().

Comment: @saeed: No, I didn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You created form 2 after emitting the signal. and the pointer in m_pForm1 is completely new Form and is useless. change your code like this :

```
Form1::Form1()//change your constructor depending on your need
{
   m_pForm2 = new Form2;
   form2->setModal(true);
   connect(this, SIGNAL(sendId(int)), m_pForm2, SLOT(receiveId(int))); 
}

void Form1::on_btnOK_clicked()
{
   m_pForm2->show();
   emit SendId(2);            //ID = 2

}
```

Comment: I changed my code which followed your instruction. It works now. Thanks very much!

Comment: There's no need to use signals here, I'm always create a method like `Form2::show(int param)` in such situations, it's faster and much more clear to reader

Answer (score 1):

I guess it's because the Form1 instance you're listening to is never raising a signal.

Suppose you start creating an instance of Form1, show it and click on the OK button. Then, this instance of Form1 raises a signal, but no one is listening yet:

```
void Form1::on_btnOK_clicked()
{
   emit SendId(2); // No one is listening yet

   Form2 form2;
   form2.setModal(true);
   form2.exec();
}
```

A Form2 instance is then created and shown, which inside creates another Form1 instance. Form2 connects to the new Form1 **SendId** signal, but this signal is never emitted because this **new Form1 is never shown**:

```
Form2::Form2(QWidget *parent) :
QDialog(parent),
ui(new Ui::Form2)

{
   ui->setupUi(this);
   m_pForm1 = new Form1(this);  // You're creating a new Form1 instance, but you never show it
    QObject::connect(m_pForm1, SIGNAL(SendId(int)),
                     this, SLOT(ReceiveId(int))); // SendId signal of the new Form1 is never raised
}
```

Comment: After reading your comment, I understood more about my problem. Thanks bro!

Answer (score 1):

I think you're doing it wrong.
You're creating new `Form1` object in `Form2`'s constructor, and it seems like user will newer see it and no methods will be called so no signals is emitted.

When you want to send data between forms using signals, it should look like this:
*You have `Form1` and `Form2` objects, both are created and likely both are visible to user at the same time.

Then you call `connect()` to connect `Form1`'s signal to `Form2`'s slot

Then you `emit` signal in `Form1`, so `Form2`'s slot is called and data is transmitted*

If your forms is not intended to be on the screen simultaneously, just send data when you're creating `Form2` in `Form1` without signals and slots.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation! I understand about my issue clearly. And I have fixed it. Thanks bro!